# How to make excel loop back to 0 and continue counting when over a certain number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like for excel to loop back to 0 when going over the number 30, but also continue counting.

so for example: If i have the number 11 and 25, and i make a sum of it, i would like it to display 6 and not 36.

How would i do it using a formula and not a macro?

Comment: `=MOD(11+25,30)`.

Comment: @BigBen if one does not do the `-1` and `+1` we would get `0` instead of `30` for `11` and `19`

Comment: @ScottCraner - wasn't sure if OP wanted 30 or 0.

Comment: @BigBen which I can see and is why I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MOD to return the remainder:

```
=MOD((25+11)-1,30)+1
```

[image]

The above formula will return `30` for something like `11` and `19` if that is not wanted and infact it goes `28,29,0` then remove the `-1` and `+1`:

```
=MOD(11+25,30)
```

Comment: whats the -1,30)+1 used for?

Comment: @JP2K see edit for explaination.  If you want it to go `28,29,30,1,2` then you want them.  If you want `28,29,0,1,2` then you do not.

Comment: If this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark (✓) by the answer.

Comment: Oh wait. i just found out it doesnt work with 1.

So if i do for example: =MOD(1+10, 24)
It will display 0

Comment: you did not ask about '24', but I get `11` not `0` with that.